# golang: encoding/json элементы массива разных типов данных внутри общего массива

Tags: golang

Если имею структуру данных json, где по ключу *abc* хранится массив элементов одного типа данных, то могу эти элементы получить так:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// var s = `{"abc":[["a"], [-0.0025], ["2022-09-20 15:20:06"], [null], [1663676406219]]}`
   var s = `{"abc":["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]}`

func main() {
    var f map[string]interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
    }

    d := []string{}
    for key := range f {
        d = append(d, key)
    }

    f1 := f[d[0]].([]interface{}) // т.е. f1 := f["abc"].(map[string]interface{})

    m := []string{}

    for h := range f1 {
        m = append(m, f1[h].(string))
    }

    fmt.Println("m = ", m)
    for i := 0; i < len(m); i++ {
        fmt.Println(m[i])
    }
}
```

- 

```
  m =  [a b c d e]
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
```

Если имею по ключу *массив массивов*, в которых элементы имеют разный тип данных, как приведено в коде выше, то вывести такие данные не получается. Порядок следования таких различных типов данных не постоянный.

Для случая, когда внутри таких массивов лежат элементы одного типа, например, *string* , - внутри цикла работает так:

```
m = append(m, f1[h].([]interface{})[0].(string))
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
f1 =  [[a] [b] [c] [d] [e]]
a
b
c
d
e
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить элементы для такого случая:

```
 1.  var s = `{"abc":[["a"], [-0.0025], ["2022-09-20 15:20:06"], [null], [1663676406219]]}`
```

и как правильно делать, если внутри массивов имею несколько элементов и они тоже разных типов:

```
 2.  var s = `{"abc":[[33, "a"], [48, -0.0025], [55, "2022-09-20 15:20:06"], [77, null], [88, 1663676406219]]}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить элементы в случае с вложенными массивами, представьте `f1[h]` как вложенный массив `[]interface{}`:

```go
for h := range f1 {
    for x := range f1[h].([]interface{}) {
        m = append(m, fmt.Sprint(f1[h].([]interface{})[x]))
    }
}
```

В этом случае строковым представлением интерфейса занимается функция `fmt.Sprint`. Если вы хотите самостоятельно обработать каждый элемент вложенного массива, используйте [type switch](https://go.dev/tour/methods/16):

```
for h := range f1 {
    for x := range f1[h].([]interface{}) {
        v := f1[h].([]interface{})[x]
        
        switch castedV := v.(type) {
        case string:
            m = append(m, castedV) // castedV - строка
        case int:
            m = append(m, strconv.Itoa(castedV)) // castedV - число int
        default:
            m = append(m, fmt.Sprint(v))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо. если во вложенных массивах не один, а несколько элементов (всегда одинаковое их число), но тоже разные по типу, как приведено в вопросе (2), Ваш код сильно изменится? не смог доработать, т.к. пример (1) - был упрощён для ясности.

Comment: @Alex код не изменится, ибо массив остаётся массивом.

Comment: Ваш код работает, thanks.